# Como fazer um UPDATE com SqEL expression?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-boot

Estou tentando fazer um UPDATE e não estou conseguindo, alguém consegue identificar um ponto de falha ?

```
@Query(value="UPDATE cliente SET nome = #{#cliente.nome} WHERE id_cliente = 1", nativeQuery=true)
Cliente updateName(@Param("cliente") Cliente cliente);
```

O Erro exibido no Console é esse:

```
2020-01-24 23:25:17.966 ERROR 14368 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
  Posição: 28
```

Comment: `#cliente.nome`? nunca vi essa sintaxe, não seria `:cliente.nome`? além disso, está usando na query `cliente.nome`, mas esta atribuindo o parâmetro como `@Param("cliente")`, me parece que não vai funcionar...

Comment: @RicardoPontual essa é a sintaxe utilizada pelo [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions)

Comment: humm interessante @nullptr nunca usei assim, obrigado por compartilhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a sintaxe da [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions), parece que você esqueceu um `:` antes do parâmetro:

```
@Query(value="UPDATE cliente SET nome = :#{#cliente.nome} WHERE id_cliente = 1", nativeQuery=true)
Cliente updateName(@Param("cliente") Cliente cliente);
```

Provavelmente você irá trocar também o valor do `id_cliente`, poderá ser feito da mesma forma, senão você irá atualizar apenas o ID 1.

É importante também pontuar que essa sintaxe está disponível a partir do **Spring Data JPA 1.4**, então caso ainda não funcione verifique se você está utilizando a versão compatível com essa funcionalidade.